# How do I ensure robust notification of mouseup?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, mouseup

The goal is to be reliably notified of mouseup events. As a concrete example, when you left-click the cloud should turn red and when you release the button it should return to blue.

This fiddle basically works:

```
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    if (e.button === 0) {
        drawShape("#FF69B4", "red");
    }
});
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
    if (e.button === 0) {
        drawShape("#8ED6FF", "blue");
    }
});
window.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
    if (e.button === 0) {
        drawShape("#8ED6FF", "blue");
    }
}, true);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f1x6vc0c/1/

The GREAT EVIL that remains is the CONTEXT MENU. If you click the cloud, drag anywhere you like, and then right-click to get the context menu and then release the left mouse button while the context menu is present that mouseup is forever lost. Sure, I could disable the context menu, but only on pages I control - note the same aberrant behavior occurs if you activate a context-menu in some other app outside the browser window. So, how do I ensure I get notified even in this case? in a cross-browser manner?

(feel free to ignore IE prior to 9 and similarly elder browsers)